# CodeIgniter - Attach functions to View to be called on all pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a e-commerce using codeigniter. I'm done with almost all the views and I am starting the coding (controllers and models) now. 
For the login, my ideia is set its form on the "top view".

The problem is that I have to call the "top view" in every controller and configure the form_validation everytime I call it.
There is a proper way to dealing with it?

Comment: What do you mean by the "top view". ideally the login view should only be called once. Once the user is logged in, it shouldn't display again.
You can handle this with through sessions

Comment: Well, the user can can run throught the site without necessarily been logged, but the form would be right at the top whenever he decides to log in or register. I was thinking about doing a login controller that would be called when he hits the submit.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to solve the problem of how to handle commonly recurring html snippets that load on many different pages.

One solution is to add a helper function to each controller like the `render_page()` function shown below. [NOTE: Any dynamic data that is needed in any of the views to be loaded should be passed via the $data argument.]

```
protected function render_page($main_view, $data=null){
  $this->load->view('top_view', $data);
  $this->load->view('menu_view');
  if(isset($main_view)){
      $this->load->view($main_view);
  }
  $this->load->view('footer_view');
}
```

Elsewhere in the same controller

```
public function index(){
  //do stuff including setting $data as needed
  $this->render_page('some_view', $data);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that you need to define `render_page()` in every controller. To get around this, use the `render_page()` idea in a custom library (class) that works in a similar fashion. You then autoload that library and use its `render_page()` method in any controller you want.

If you made such a library and named it `Viewmaster` then you would use it in a controller as follows  (assumes it was autoloaded)

```
public function index(){
   //do stuff including setting $data as needed
   $this->viewmaster->render_page("some_view", $data);
 }
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out the implementation details of the `Viewmaster` class.

Comment: So can I process the form validation within this function? I tried to submit the form inside the "top view" pointing the action to the login controller. But it acused the form_validation method of not being defined.

Comment: No, form validation would not happen in this function. Its purpose is only to gather and display multiple view files that make up a page. However, you would use `render_page()`  inside the function that is handling validation. For validation setup, read the [documentation about using a config file](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#saving-sets-of-validation-rules-to-a-config-file) to have a reuseable set of   rules..

Comment: This post main problem was not the view setup itself, the problem was having to write the same form validation code everytime I set up a page.

Comment: @kaio_san, what version of CodeIgniter are you using?